# regex to match first half of any string?

Tags: javascript, regex

I find this hard to do without variable quantifiers

I'd like to be able to do something like

```
var halfStrLength = string.length /2 


string = string.replace(/.(?=.{halfStrLength})/g, '*') 
// replaces all but the last half of string with *
```

Comment: how it should replace if `str.length` is odd?

Comment: I don't think that regex is the correct tool for this

Comment: Maaaybe with recursive patterns, if you want to enjoy a challenge.

Answer (score 2):

Consider using `str.slice(beginIndex[, endIndex])` instead. It returns a new string.

You might want to round the halfStrLength down or up, as you don’t want to try and split a string in half by a decimal.

Answer (score 1):

You may create new RegExp like this:

```
    var times = string.length / 2;
    var regexp = new RegExp('(.{'+times+'})');

    string = string.replace(regexp,'*');
```

Answer (score 0):

> replaces all but the last half of string with `*`

Simply with `String.substr()` and `String.padStart()` (Ecmascript 6) functions:

```js
var s = 'halfStrLength',
    half = s.substr(s.length / 2).padStart(s.length, '*');
  
console.log(half);
```